# Replacing the motherboard with a different one in an HP z2 Tower G9

Tags: motherboard

I have the following PC that I just purchased, but I don't care for the BIOS, and when I enable Hypervisor and install Hyper-V in windows server 2022 it will no longer boot.  I have spent many hours in troubleshooting this.  I like the system as a whole, but I am use to custom built PC's.

My question is, if I purchase a motherboard that is compactable with the CPU, RAM, etc, will I be able to use the existing chassis and the PSU?  If not, do you have suggestions?

PC: https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-z2-tower-g9-workstation-desktop-pc/2100987204/manuals

Motherboard that I would like to replace it with: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1668940-REG/msi_pro_z690_a_lga_1700.html

The PC that I purchased: https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1700670-REG/hp_6h907ut_aba_z2_g9_twr_i712700.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not gonna happen

That PC has a custom PSU/mobo/case and they need to be replaced all at the same time to avoid incompatibilities or the case screws shorting out the back of the new mobo. Since that PC uses the HP Z2 Workstation standard for motherboard and PSU, it can't be replaced with ATX components.

For next time, maybe check out r/buildapc or this site before getting a new PC

Comment: Thanks, I normally build my own, but I wanted to fast track this lab that I have and purchase something less expensive, not sure that I'll do that again.